# install jenkins with java thats in a specifed folder

Tags: jenkins

I want to update jenkins(currently using jdk 6;to upgrade jenkins i need jdk7) but so, many application in my jenkins server use jdk6.So, I cannot update java.So, I want to copy java binary in folder like /home/username/java and I want to make jenkins use /home/username/java while updating.So, the other programs don't get disturbed(Most of them use which java and get the java installation example:maven and some other tools I am not aware of).Is there a config file which can be edited to make jenkins use a java in a specific folder(while installing or updating).

Comment: Just wondering if my answer solved your issue. If so, please accept the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

There is a JDK dropdown in "job name" -> Configure in Jenkins web UI. It will list all JDKs available in Jenkins configuration.

You can add new JDKs through Manage Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> JDK.

Here is a visual of where you should configure additional JDKs in Jenkins:
[image: Jenkins JDK Config]